# How to get values greater than or equal to in Mysql database sql when its a value like 1:00 PM?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying make an sql query that uses the users current time as a variable formatted like "11:30 AM". Then, finds records greater than equal to that in the mysql db.

```
if(isset($_GET['curday'])){
   $curday = $_GET['curday']; // users current day value 5 for Friday
}

if(isset($_GET['time'])){
   $time = $_GET['time']; // users current time value 11:30AM

   $time = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $time);  // replacing the : and AM,PM

         $query = "SELECT id, Name, Address, Meeting_type, Latitude, Longitude, Thetime, Gender, Dayofweek, 3956 * 2 *
     ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat - Latitude)*pi()/180/2),2)
     +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(Latitude*pi()/180)
     *POWER(SIN(($origLon-Longitude)*pi()/180/2),2)))
     as Distance FROM $tableName WHERE
     Longitude between ($origLon-$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69)
     and ($origLon+$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69)
     and Latitude between ($origLat-($dist/69))
     and ($origLat+($dist/69))
     having Distance < $dist AND Meeting_type = $id AND Dayofweek = $curday AND Thetime >= $time ORDER BY Thetime limit 100";

}
```

I know the AM and PM effect finding a >= value and possibly the : in the time value so I removed all but the numbers to try to help using
   $time = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $time); but still can't retrieve values properly. I can't use timestamp in this existing database so would prefer a solution without. It's local for now and I will put sql injection security in after I get this working.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: what is the type of `Thetime` column in the database?

Comment: And what do the times in the DB look like?

Comment: @GiacomoM varchar 15.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - 1:00 AM with space in between

Comment: I tried to make the query smaller its way bigger @AbraCadaver - I'll put the full thing in.

Comment: No what is the `Thetime` data in the database?  Just `100` or `1:00` or `1:00 AM`?

Comment: its 1:00 AM @AbraCadaver

Comment: MInd SQL injection, as your code seams to be prone to that kind of attack..

Comment: @RaymondNijland oh yes its all local for now then I'll put that good stuff in.

Comment: As SQL is a  declarative language.. see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also keep in mind that `ORDER BY Thetime limit 100` is non deterministic ("random") where the `Thetime` column values ties.. Meaning on every run the results might change even when the data is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best way, but given what you have you could do:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Thetime, '[^0-9]', '') >= $time
```

But keep in mind that `12:00 PM` or `1200` in this case will be greater than `1:00 PM` or `100`, which is not correct.  So you might want to convert to 24 hour time:

```
$time = date('Hi', strtotime($time));
```

Then:

```
DATE_FORMAT(TheTime, '%H%i') >= $time
```

So from the previous example of `12:00 PM` and `1:00 PM`, you will have `1200` and `1300`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` mysql function to format your `VAR_CHAR` column to date and apply your `WHERE` clause to it.

In your case you will have a SELECT like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(TheTime, "%H:%i %p") > your_value_formatted ORDER BY TheTime
```